# phpmyadmin not recognizing my sql

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
CREATE TABLE administrator
{
    administrator_Email varchar(50) not null,
    administrator_Password  varchar(50) not null,
    administrator_Name  varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (administrator_Email)
};
```

I am trying to import a database in phpmyadmin. For some reason it is giving me an error and I am not sure why. I tried entering just this table manually and it still did not work. I am a SQL novice and I am wondering why this is happening, it seems like it is the same as other examples that do work in phpmyadmin.

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '{
    administrator_Email    varchar(50)    not null,
    administrator_Password    varchar(5' at line 2**

This bold content is the error phpmyadmin gives when I click "go"

Thanks in advance,
Kirie

Comment: that did not change anything...

Comment: Remove opening and closing braces and add Brackets like()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your opening and closing braces with parentheses. `{` -> `(`

[Not the greatest resource](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-create-table.htm), but it's a quick view at the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE administrator
(
    administrator_Email varchar(50) not null,
    administrator_Password  varchar(50) not null,
    administrator_Name  varchar(50) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (administrator_Email)
);
```